# Looks like this is an Ionic Angular project, would you like to install @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular and continue?

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

Im fairly new to ionic. im trying to run ionic serve on the command line but keep getting this message below

> **Looks like this is an Ionic Angular project, would you like to install @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular and continue?**

even when i say yes it completes successfully and then comes back

Comment: _and then comes back_ what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The new Ionic CLI v3 have few changes, now works with plugins. Here you can read the [blog](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-cli-v3/)

But you just need to run:

`npm i -g ionic cordova`to install ionic y cordova

If you are using the new CLI install the new plugins and then just run:

`ionic start myApp blank --v2` to create a new app with Ionic 2+